# Match Adjusted Indirect Comparison with continuous and categorical variables

Tags: r, matching

I am attempting to replicate the analysis here: http://nicedsu.org.uk/technical-support-documents/population-adjusted-indirect-comparisons-maic-and-stc/ (see appendix D). Specifically, the MAIC in order to compare individual patient data (IPD) with aggregate published data (AgD).

Pages 4 and 5 describe how I would do matching for the patient weights. But the weights are coming out with unexpected values. I think I'm having trouble with the categorical variables. Specifically - creating centred versions of the effect modifiers, where the code is:

```
X.EM.0 <- sweep(with(AB.IPD, cbind(age, age^2)), 2,
                with(AC.AgD, c(age.mean, age.mean^2 + age.sd^2)), '-')
```

If hypothetically I wanted to use the sweep function on categorical variables (where the IPD shows a Y/N binary) and the AgD data reports a proportion of patients, what would I need to do to make the sweep work (e.g. Should I subtract the % of patients reported  in the AgD data from the Y/N binary of the IPD?)